# Can't fetch data from API using Vue and Axios

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm creating an e-learning website where there are cards of courses that you can pick. Here are my codes

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-container>
      <v-row>
          <v-col md="3" offset-lg="1">
              <Categories />
          </v-col>
          <v-col md="9" lg="7">
              <CourseList v-bind:list="list"/>
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import CourseList from '@/components/courses/CourseList.vue'
import Categories from '@/components/courses/Categories.vue'
import axios from 'axios'


export default {
  components: {
    CourseList,
    Categories
  },
  data() {
         return {
            list: []
         }
  },
  mounted: function() {
            axios
                .get('https://esl3usx3t7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing1/api/get_course')
                .then(res => this.list = res.body)
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
}
</script>
```

CourseList.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h2>Courses</h2>

      <v-row>
          <v-col sm="6" md="4">
              <VerticalCard v-bind:list="list"/>
              
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VerticalCard from '@/components/cards/VerticalCard.vue'

export default {
    name: "CourseList",
    components: {
        VerticalCard
    },
    props: ["list"]
}
</script>
```

My problem is I haven't been able to fetch the data from API link ->
https://esl3usx3t7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing1/api/get_course

I wonder what am I doing wrong. I have also tried to use {{list}} to get the data, but it didn't work. My goal right now is to get all the data even though it will look messy. Sorry for my bad English and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

axios wraps data in data object so instead of `.then(res => this.list = res.body)`it should be`.then(res => this.list = res.data.body)`

Answer (score 1):

every data response that requested by axios will wrap in `data` object, so you need to get body data from `data.body`. you can check by `console.log(res)`

```
const uri = 'https://esl3usx3t7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing1/api/get_course'
axios
  .get(uri)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    let {data: {statusCode, body}} = res
    if(statusCode == 200)
      this.list = [...body]
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```